# Using MemCache in IAsyncActionFilter

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have this class in my project that I want to speed up by using a memcache:

```
 [AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ApiKeyAuthAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private string accessKey;
    private string apiKey;
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        
        context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MemoryCache>();
        var connection = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApiKeyContext>();

        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(key:"ApiKey", out var potentialApiKey))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(key: "Client", out var apiClient);
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue<string>(apiClient, out accessKey))
        {
            apiKey = connection.ApiKey.Where(x => x.Client == apiClient.ToString()).Select(x => x.Apikey1).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(key: "ApiKey", out var clientApiKey);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
        {
            if (!apiKey.Equals(clientApiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Here is my startup class ConfigureService method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<ApiKeyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiKey")));
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    }
```

I can inject the EntityFramework context and access it without any problems, and I can pull the key from the database for the supplied client to match the APIKey.  Now, I want to increase the speed of key retrieval by putting the apiKey into a memcache.  However, when I try to request the Service using GetRequiredService() I get this error:

> No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache' has been registered.

I can't inject the memcache in the constructor because the interface implementation does not allow an interface.  So how can I set up the memcache to be injected using the GetRequiredServices method on context.HttpContext.RequestServices?

Comment: You should be requesting `IMemoryCache` and *not* `MemoryCache`. The latter is the *implementation* type, the former is what is actually registered as the *Service* type when you use `AddMemoryCache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MemoryCache>();
```

to

```
context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
```